# Dynamic global variables in C

Tags: c, variables, dynamic, global-variables

Can someone please explain to why this won't work:

```
int DIM = 128, hDIM = DIM/2 , dDIM = DIM*2;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

     DIM *= 2;

     printf("\n Double DIM is %d \n",dDIM);

}
```

Why does this print 256 instead of 512?

Comment: changing `DIM` doesn't automatically change `dDIM`, `dDIM` has the same value you initialized it with unless you change it directly (or through a pointer or reference, but neither of those apply here)

Comment: How can I code it so it changes dynamically?

Comment: there's no notion in C++ of variables automatically updating based on each other's values--at least not built-in to the language. if you want to update both variables you need to update both variables yourself.

Comment: a "function" is the notion of something that changes dynamically with respect to a variable.  so halfDim()  and doubleDim() can dynmically calculate what you want

Comment: having said that, you could use #defines to do what you want,  but seriously not reccomended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I code it so it changes dynamically?

You can use functions instead of global variables:

```
int DIM = 128;

int hDIM(void) { return DIM / 2; }

int dDIM(void) { return DIM * 2; }

int main(int argc, char **argv){
     DIM *= 2;
     printf("\n Double DIM is %d \n",dDIM());
}
```

This way, `hDIM` and `dDIM` are evaluated based on the current value of `DIM` each time you use them. The way your code was, values were assigned to `hDIM` and `dDIM` only once, at the beginning of the program, using the value that DIM had at that point.

Comment: I had tried this initially whilst debugging but a second bug in the code made me think it wasn't working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because `dDim` is evaluated before the `main` is executed. At the start - before `main` function is called, `DIM` is 128. `dDim = 2 * DIM` which means `dDim` is 256.

Then `main()` function is called, `DIM` is set to 256. But all of this has no effect on `dDim`.

> How can I code it so it changes dynamically?

You can use the method mentioned by Caleb below or you can use Preprocessor macros.

```
int DIM = 128;

#define hDIM ((DIM) / 2)
#define dDIM ((DIM) * 2)

int main() {
  DIM *= 2;
  printf("%d", dDIM); /*prints 512 :-)*/
  return 0;
}
```

I however do not recommend the above method. It is nasty and hard to debug. 
For example, it fails this test:

```
assert_equal_float(2.5f, hDIM);/*when DIM is 5*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you only modified the value of `DIM` in your main() function whereas `dDim` is untouched after is initial value of `256` i.e `(128 * 2)`.

```
int DIM = 128, hDIM = DIM/2 , dDIM = DIM*2;
```

The above statement sets the values as follows:

```
DIM = 128
hDIM = 64
dDIM = 256
```

In `main()` when you do `DIM *= 2`, you only modify the value of DIM. The remaining variables will not be re-evaluated since you did not do any further assignment to `hDIM` or `dDIM`.